# MongoDB how to add conditional $match condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following schema

```
{
   f1: "test",
   f2: "something",
   type: "A",
   date: "2018-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
   deleted: false
},
{
   "f1": "check",
   type: "B",
   deleted: false
}
```

Now what I want is to get all data, and if `type = "A", then add an extra condition to my match query, suppose compare its date with current date`.
My current query is:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
  {$match:{
        {"deleted":false},
        // I want to check if type is A then compare its date 
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try an `$or` and say "If it's not type A **or** the date is x":

```
{$match:{
  $and: [
    {deleted: false},
    $or: [
      {type: {$ne: 'A'}},
      {date: {$gte: ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00.0Z"), $lt: ISODate("2018-06-01T00:00:00.0Z")}}
    ]
  ]
}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `$match` with `$or` condition.

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([
  { $match: {
    $or : [
      { "deleted": false, "type": "A", "date": ISODate("2018-11-01T00:00:00.000Z") },
      { "deleted": false, type: { $ne: "A" }}
    ]}
  }
])
```